# Проверка isset($_FILES[filename]) не работает

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.
В форме есть поле `<input type="file" name="filename" />`
При отправке формы идёт проверка

```
if (isset($_FILES['filename'])) { //что-то делаем... }
```

На тестовом сайте, где я всё это кодил, проверка на isset работала нормально, однако, после переноса на хостинг клиента, работать перестала.
То есть, даже если я не загружаю через форму никакого файла, скрипт всё равно считает, что какой-то файл загружен.
В чём может быть проблема? В настройках хостинга? Как её решить, не меняя настройки хостинга? Или обязательно что-то менять? Спасибо.

Comment: В форме стоит тип `enctype="multipart/form-data"`? Если стоит, то покажите, что выводит команда `var_dump(ini_get('enable_post_data_reading'), ini_get('post_max_size'), ini_get('upload_max_filesize'), ini_get('max_file_uploads'), $_FILES);` там, где вы файл пытаетесь поймать.

Comment: попробуйте проверку if (!empty($_FILES['filename'])) {...}

Comment: Еще проверте права на запись во временную папку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы использовал вместо

```
if (isset($_FILES['filename']))
  {
   ...
  }
```

другую конструкцию:

```
if ($_FILES['filename']['name'] != "") 
  {
   ...
  }
```

или даже так:

```
if (isset($_FILES['filename']['name']) && ($_FILES['filename']['name'] != ''))
   {
    ...
   }
```

По крайней мере, у меня вторая и третья конструкция работают, а ваша - нет.

Comment: Во 2м варианте возможна ошибка при отсутствии ключа name в массиве или в принципе отсутвия массива. Например если не выбрали файл.

Answer (score 1):

`$_FILES['filename']['size'] != 0`

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Функция [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php) вернёт `TRUE`, даже если значение переменной пустая строка.

> isset — Определяет, была ли установлена переменная значением, отличным от `NULL`

Другими словами, она определена и содержит пустую строку, а пустая строка это не `NULL`.